# Writing accented characters to Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

I have to update an existing script so that it writes some data to an Oracle 10g database.  The script and the database both run on the same Solaris 10 (Intel) machine.  Python is v2.4.4.

I'm using cx_Oracle and can read/write to the database with no problem.  But the data I'm writing contains accented characters which are not getting written correctly.  The accented character turns into an upside-down question mark.

The value is read from a binary file with this code, in :

```
class CustomerHeaderRecord:
    def __init__( self, rec, debug = False ):
        self.record = rec
        self.acct   = rec[ 84:104 ]
```

And the contents of the `acct` variable displays on-screen correctly.

Below is the code that writes to the db (the `acct` value is passed in as the `val_1` variable):

```
class MQ:
    def __init__( self, rec, debug = False ):
        self.customer_record = CustomerHeaderRecord( rec, debug )
        self.add_record(self.customer_record.acct, self.cm_custid)

    def add_record(self, val_1, val_2):
        cur = conn.cursor()
        qry = "select count(*) from table_name where value1 = :val1"
        cur.execute(qry, {'val1':val_1})
        count = cur.fetchone()
        if count[0] == 0:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            qry = "insert into table_name (value1, value2) values(:val1, :val2)"
            cur.execute(qry, {'val1':val_1, 'val2':val_2})
            conn.commit()
```

The `acct` value doesn't make it to the database correctly.  I've googled a bunch of stuff about unicode and UTF-8 but haven't found anything that helps me yet.  In the database, the NLS_LANGUAGE is 'American' and the NLS_CHARACTERSET is 'AL32UTF8'.

Do I need to 'do something' to/with the `acct` variable before/during the insert?

Comment: What is the output of `print repr(acct)`? Your data is most likely already encoded, but not in the UTF-8 encoding used by Oracle.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - it displays as `'PF R\xe9solu Canada Inc'`.  When just printed without `repr`, it's `PF Résolu Canada Inc`.

Comment: That's Latin-1; I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file appears to be encoding in Latin-1. Decode this to `unicode` data; cx_Oracle will do the rest for you:

```
acct    = rec[ 84:104 ].decode('latin1')
```

or use the [`codecs.open()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to open the file for automatic decoding:

```
inputfile = codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin1')
```

Reading from `inputfile` will give you `unicode` data.

On insertion, the `cx_Oracle` library will encode `unicode` values to the correct encoding that Oracle expects. You *do* need to set the `NLS_LANG` environment variable to `AL32UTF8` before connecting, either in the shell or in Python with:

```
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8"
```

You may want to review the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more details.

Comment: Using `rec[ 84:104 ].decode('latin1')` resulted in a `UnicodeEncodeError' of `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 259: ordinal not in range(128)'.  Similar result with `codecs.open`.

Comment: No, `rec[ 84:104 ].decode('latin1')` itself did not result in that error; note that it is a *encode* error, while that statement is doing a decode instead. You are either printing the result to a log file or to a dumb terminal; python is auto-converting the `unicode` value back to ASCII because that's the only way it can try and combine a `unicode` value and byte codes or printing it to a output file.

Comment: In the context of the code shown so far, this should work. If not, can you show us the *full* traceback (edit your question).

Comment: Yes, I was indeed printing the value and that's where the error was being thrown.  I've removed the print and now have a different error when trying to use the `acct` value in a query.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: If I add `.decode('latin1')` as suggested, I get a `TypeError - not enough arguments for format string` when it gets to the line that executes the select statement; ie, where I try to use that acct/val_1 value.

Comment: @DaveKub: That sounds like something altogether different is going wrong; did you change the number of parameters being passed in? Is there a more complete traceback other than just the `TypeError`?

Comment: Argh, my newness to Python is showing.  Ignore the `TypeError` comment/error; was my fault.  I'm getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)` when I try to use the acct/val_1 at the `cur.execute(qry, {'val1':val_1})` line.

Comment: @DaveKub: What version of cx_Oracle is this?

Comment: I'm using cx_Oracle v5.1.2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24128/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-davekub)

Comment: adding the `.decode('latin1')` and setting the NLS_LANG env var solved my issue.  Thank you very much!